# how could we access the images located outside the expo project?

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a mobile app by expo (react native), I would like to display profile image, knowing that the images are located outside my project.
when I want to access any image I do not get there, and I get this type of error
"SHA-1 for file (D:\Workspace\ImagesProfile\images3.jpg) is not computed".
this is the hierarchy of my workspace.
-Workspace
--ImagesProfile
--Myproject
Pleace how can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The way the react-native packager works right now, it's just going to scan the roots of your project and below when creating the JavaScript bundle, so it will be really hard to do this.

You basically just need to put the files under the root of your directory. There are some tools out there for syncing files from another directory into a directory under the root so you could use one of those if you really need to.

Some people are working on ways to make symlinks work with this. Notably, you might look at Haul from Callstack. https://github.com/callstack-io/haul But that isn't integrated into Expo yet.

Answer (score 1):

Okay at first you should understand what you are doing. You're creating a react native application, which means this application is running on external devices and not on your PC. Your simulator or expo client running your application encapsulated from your PC using only project files. When you wanna use external images in your application you need to host them. You can create a local docker instance as image server ( e.g. an express application with a static folder ).

To make it clear, it's not possible to use images inside your filesystem which are not a part of your react native application. You can use external image server like "imgbb" for test purposes, but it's not recommended to use them in your final version.

Happy Coding!